# Sync Vue.js data with some existing html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js clientside, and populate a list as follows (this works after an ajax/json api request which I populate with Vue data and methods).

```
<div id="myDiv1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.title }}
  </li>
</div>
```

I currently intialise Vue with

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
...
  data: {
    items: {},
  },
  methods: { ajaxCallAndUpdateVueItems: function(){...} 
  } 
})

ajaxCallAndUpdateVueItems() on some event
```

However, I would like to preload/render on the server side an initial state of the list (for a few reasons like speed, seo, initialstate first time only). This state varies depending on things like location of the user, which the server calculates.

So I want to send the initial page to the client with

```
<div id="myDiv1"> 
  <li>Some title1</li>
  <li>Some title2</li>
</div>
```

Is there any way to somehow initialise the Vue data with the content of myDiv1 for example, so I don't have 2 sets of html I somehow mess with (e.g deleting the initial html block and repopulating via Vue) ?

Comment: Are the values in the `li` tags static? If so, why not hard-code the items in `data.items`?

Comment: Hi Alvin, they aren't static, and would vary on things like your location

Comment: Have your HTML spit out `<script>var foobar = [ items ];</script>` (where `items` is your array of items) and initialize the data as `items: items`.

Comment: I was hoping to initialize the page with html rather than js for seo reasons, but it is one route I will explore thanks.

Comment: Google still crawls data that is in synchronous Javascript.  If you do what @ceejayoz said, you'll get the SEO value. It's only when you have to fetch something with AJAX that Google doesn't index it. https://vuejs.org/guide/ssr.html

Comment: ceejayoz, thanks this certainly works as one option. I've output JSON.stringify( item ) from the server and I can populate it initially. I'm still interested in if there is any 'link' somehow from html elements to the vue data the other way around, but if you want to post an answer, I will upvote, and likely accept.